# Why are configuration functions that "return this" common in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It seems to be a common javascript convention to configure objects with methods called one after the other, for example

```
toy.setColor(blue).setPrice(5).setName('Blocks').setPurchaseAction(function(customer){
   ...
})
```

and so on.

Coming from a more java based background I am used to splitting up each of those method calls into separate statements, separated by a semicolon.

It probably doesn't matter when compiled into machine level language but the practice of splitting with semicolons seems like it makes code easier to read/understand. Is there a good reason for doing it like this in javascript?

Comment: It's called method chaining and the main purpose of using it is readability. People usually break lines before the dots.

Comment: Is there a good reason? Depends on who you ask. It's a matter of opinion if it's good or not.

Comment: For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: `Coming from a more java based background` - imagine someone coming from a Cobol or Fortran background, equally irrelevant

Comment: You can do exactly the same in Java (and there are libraries that use this). Maybe JS coders are more used to it because jQuery, but the pros and cons are exactly the same.

Comment: I would rather see JS get a special operator that lets you override the return value with the object, [like Dart has](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-). Then methods could have a more meaningful return value, and you can still chain if you don't care about those values. Either way, this feature is way over-hyped, and often a mess to read.

Comment: Saves bandwidth, saves typing, easier to read as it's more in sync with how people talk. You don't say "I want a toy that's blue. I want that toy to have a price of 5. I want that toy to have a name Blocks." Why repeat yourself? "I want a blue toy with a price of 5 and the name Blocks."

Comment: @squint If you are using pure functions (that return a *new* instance instead of altering their `this` value), that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Bergi: You wouldn't want to use it when you care about the return value, if that's what you mean. It would only be used if you specifically want the original object instead of the returned value... if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: @squint Oh, "special operator" implies that you can choose of course… Right, then there's only the (dis)advantage? that the library cannot swap out their implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern is named "method chaining" and the main advantage of such an approach is that when no need exists to hold on to a placeholder at each step then the next method may simply be called as a continuation.

Further, this type of approach is well suited for deferred execution, and many languages use such an approach. In JavaScript you can see this being used in the new-ish promise features which favor method chaining over what some refer to as "callback hell" in JavaScript.

Overall, it is just preference as it does not offer any performance benefits to use method chaining versus iteratively calling methods. However, it does read very nicely in my opinion, and the pattern pairs very well with other similar approaches.

Comment: Another term for "callback hell" is just outright "pyramid code." In addition, I'm surprised you haven't mentioned the new proposal syntax for `async await` which offers an even greater benefit of readability as it allows asynchronous code to look as if it was synchronous.